# how to keep the multi-screen configuration even after turning off main monitor?

Tags: laptop, windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, script

Currently have 1 laptop and 1 monitor. Before my recent Windows 10 update, I could close my laptop screen and the monitor would still function as the secondary monitor. This was useful, because I can concentrate on doing stuff.

But after the update, somehow, when I close my laptop monitor, the laptop monitor goes off the listing, and the external monitor becomes the main one.

Is there a way to revert this? Or somehow turn off the screen of my laptop screen until i want it back on? Because I saw some commands like this:

```
%systemroot%\system32\scrnsave.scr /s
```

But they turn off both of the monitors, and reactivates after pressing any key...

Maybe set a bat file on laptop desktop to turn off laptop screen (maybe blank screen again?) and have another bat file to turn back on external monitor's screen to turn back on the laptop's monitor?